# Making middle component widen up over the remaining space in dock panel

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, panel, layout-manager

The docking panel has the property that the last docked control is assigned all the remaining space. That creates the effect of: ping-ping-ping-piiiing, in lack of a real visual representation.

I'd like to achieve the situation where the top most and bottom most controls are squeezed down and the remaining space is assigned to the middle control (or none at all, as the middle of the window is supposed to be empty and the visually noticeable controls will be placed only at the edges). The effect created will be: ping-ping-piiiing-ping.

Imagine that the window will have all the labels, boxes etc. at the top (docked to the top of the panel) and a stack panel with a bunch of buttons at the bottom (docked to the bottom of the panel and horizontally right aligned), similarly to a message box.

How can I achieve that? Perhaps dock panel needs to be combine with some other layouter? Or perhaps I should use a different layout totally? In Swing, many years ago, there was this north/south/east/west container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the last element to be the "middle" one and take up the remaining space, you can set up this layout:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      Labels, boxes
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      Buttons here
    </StackPanel>

    <Label></Label>        

</DockPanel>
```

It that what you mean? Please note that the last element (the empty label) has no docking.
Usually this approach is used if the "last child" represents some expandable UI control (or set of controls) like a ListBox.

**Alternative:**

For your goal, you could also set up a table with three rows, and give the middle row all remaining height:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />            
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">Top row</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2">Bottom row</Label>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh, I understand the approach. It's working, definitely, but I can't help feeling that it's a work-around, rather than a real solution. The reason for that is the fact that the XML-like markup is supposed not to be dependent of it's order. A sibling is a sibling. At least in the pure theory, hehe.

Comment: Yes, in this case the order is important. I guess the only alternative by the WPF design team would have been to include the name (x:key) of the child control which shall fill up the space in an attribute of the DockPanel (which would mean you have to name this element).

Comment: That'd be even more against the XMLishness, in my view. Is there another, less well-known panel or layout manager that has an empty control automatically added last to enable the behavior without me needing to do it myself?

Comment: I updated the answer using a three row table layout as alternative.

Comment: For being thorough and for a neat example +1.